# Sorting Multidimensional Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am currently trying to sort a multidimensional array of scores in Java. I am able to get the table created and the print out to print out in regular order, but I am not able to print it out in ascending order. Here is my code:

```
public class SortGrades {

    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        // Students' answers to the questions
        char[][] answers = {
                {'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
                {'E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'}};

                // Key to the questions
                char[] keys = {'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D'};
                
                // Create array for student # and correct answers
                int[][] userScores = new int[8][2];
                
                // Grade all answers
                for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
                  // Grade one student
                  int correctCount = 0;
                  for (int j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++) {
                    if (answers[i][j] == keys[j]) {
                      correctCount++;
                    }
                  userScores[i][1] = correctCount;
                  }
                }
                
                for (int row = 0; row < answers.length; row++) {
                    int value = 0;
                    int index = -1;
                    userScores[row][0] = row;
                        for (int column = row; column < answers.length; column++) {
                        if (userScores[row][1] > userScores[column][0] || value ==    
                                        userScores[column][0] 
                                && userScores[index][1] >               
                                                            userScores[column][1]) {
                            index = column;
                            value = userScores[row][1];
                        }
                        if (index == row) {
                            int temp0 = userScores[index][0];
                            int temp1 = userScores[index][1];
                            userScores[index][0] = userScores[row][0];
                            userScores[index][1] = userScores[row][1];
                            userScores[row][0] = temp0;
                            userScores[row][1] = temp1;
                    }
                    }
                }
                
                for (int row = 0; row < answers.length; row++) {
                    System.out.print("Student " + userScores[row][0] + " score is ");
                    for (int column = 0; column < answers.length; column++);
                        System.out.print(userScores[row][1] + "\n");
                    }
    }
}
```

I am very new to Java and Computer Science in general, and have not studied the advanced methods several individuals have posted. I am trying to complete this exercise without using anything but the basics for arrays and sorting.

I have tried creating a for loop with an if statement that is supposed to swap the two pairs of data if the second column number is bigger than the second. Example if what I am trying to do:

How I need it:
Student 3 score is 4
Student 2 score is 5
Student 1 score is 6
Student 0 score is 7
Student 5 score is 7
Student 6 score is 7
Student 7 score is 7
Student 4 score is 8

Comment: Why is your `userScores` a 2-dim array? The score is in in `userScores[studentId][1]`, so what's in `userScores[studentId][0]`? This code would strike me as significantly simpler if it was just a 1-dim array.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It's a 2D array because two pieces of information are being stored: `[0]` is the student number, while `[1]` is their number correct for that student. Presumably, after being sorted by the # correct, you would be still be able to know which student got that score. See the very last part of the description that says `How I need it:` which shows the scores being output in ascending order, but before each score it shows which student # got that score. So the student number needs to be swapped with the scores as they are sorted...

Comment: When u say basics, youre excluding `Arrays.sort` right?

Comment: I'd change `int[][] userScores = new int[8][2]` to `int[][] userScores = new int[answers.length][2]` so that it works for a different number of students without needing to remember to manually change the `8` to a different number.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation I would not be opposed to a sort function that works for the array. We have read about the function but I did not see a way to create the sort using a primary and secondary key.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing it would be a bubble sort.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < userScores.length - 1; i++) {
  // the outer loop keeps track of each pass of going through the list
  for (int j = 0; j < userScores.length - i - 1; j++) {
    // the inner loop checks the elements next to each other in the list
    // '-i' is used since, after every cycle of the outer loop,
    // the final i elements are correctly arranged and don't require further checking.
    // '-1' ensures that when comparing an element to its neighbor, we
    // don't go out of bounds

    if (userScores[j][1] > userScores[j + 1][1]) {
      // if the current score is greater than the following score, they need to be swapped

      // swap the two elements. 
      // (we swap the entire sub-arrays, 
      // to preserve the association student number and score)
      int[] temp = userScores[j];        // store the current element
      userScores[j] = userScores[j + 1]; // place the next element in the current position
      userScores[j + 1] = temp;          // put the saved element in the next position
    }
  }
}
```

then you can print the sorted scores like so

```java
for (int i = 0; i < userScores.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("Student " + userScores[i][0] + " score is " + userScores[i][1]);
}
```

The sorting is handled by a double `for` loop, where we compare each pair of items next to each other and swaps them if they are in the wrong order(in this case, ascending). This repeats until there are no more swaps needed, meaning the 2d array is sorted. The condition  `if (userScores[j][1] > userScores[j + 1][1])` ensures we are looking at the second element of each sub-array to determin if a swap is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the code AND the explanation in the code, that is the part I am lacking. I do not have a firm understanding of what the sort is doing. I am going through this code in my program to make sure I understand better! Again major thanks for the logic portion of the code!

Comment: @AlexTaraba no problem, and good luck in your learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sort that first sorts the scores in ascending order. If the scores are equal, then the student number is checked to sort the students for that particular score in ascending order for the student number.

```
for (int rowA = 0; rowA < answers.length-1; rowA++) {
    for (int rowB = rowA+1; rowB < answers.length; rowB++) {
        if (userScores[rowA][1] > userScores[rowB][1]) {
                int[] temp = userScores[rowA];
                userScores[rowA] = userScores[rowB];
                userScores[rowB] = temp;
        } else if (userScores[rowA][0] > userScores[rowB][0]) {
                int[] temp = userScores[rowA];
                userScores[rowA] = userScores[rowB];
                userScores[rowB] = temp;           
        }
   } 
}
```

By using a Comparator, one could simplify the process.

This says for an int array of size `2`, if the scores are not equal, then sort on them, otherwise, continue to sort on the student id.

```
Comparator<int[]> comp = Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(i -> i[1])
                .thenComparing(i -> i[0]);
  
for (int rowA = 0; rowA < answers.length-1; rowA++) {
    for (int rowB = rowA+1; rowB < answers.length; rowB++) {
        if (comp.compare(userScores[rowA], userScores[rowB]) > 0) { 
                int[] temp = userScores[rowA];
                userScores[rowA] = userScores[rowB];
                userScores[rowB] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the easiest of all.  Stream each students score and id use the previous comparator.  The internal sort is also more efficient.

```
Arrays.stream(userScores).sorted(comp).toArray(int[]::new);

Integer[] sortedScores = 
     Arrays.stream(userScores).sorted(comp).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: I will need to research more but thanks for bringing both of those methods to my attention. It would be good to learn some more advanced coding.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: just create a loop from `0` to `max amount of questions` (i.e. student can have all correct answers). In case you find a student with `currentScore` - print it.

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    /*
     * row - student
     * col - answer
     */
    char[][] answers = {
            { 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
            { 'E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' } };

    char[] validAnswers = { 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D' };
    int[] studentScores = calcStudentScores(answers, validAnswers);
    printScoresAsc(studentScores, validAnswers.length);
}

private static int[] calcStudentScores(char[][] answers, char[] validAnswers) {
    int[] scores = new int[answers.length];

    for (int studentId = 0; studentId < scores.length; studentId++)
        for (int answerId = 0; answerId < answers[studentId].length; answerId++)
            if (answers[studentId][answerId] == validAnswers[answerId])
                scores[studentId]++;

    return scores;
}

private static void printScoresAsc(int[] studentScores, int maxScore) {
    for (int score = 0; score <= maxScore; score++)
        for (int studentId = 0; studentId < studentScores.length; studentId++)
            if (studentScores[studentId] == score)
                System.out.format("Student %d score is %d\n", studentId, score);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Student 3 score is 4
Student 2 score is 5
Student 1 score is 6
Student 0 score is 7
Student 5 score is 7
Student 6 score is 7
Student 7 score is 7
Student 4 score is 8
```